# What is reasoning behind disallowing edits less than 6 characters

Tags: feature-request, edits

I get that the mods do not want people to abuse the edit system just to rack up the edit counts, but stack overflow is primarily about code. Therefore we must be exact.

I recently came across a post with a missing parenthesis, other than that it was spot on. This may only take someone a few seconds/minutes to find if they copy paste, but why make it hard to correct this.

Maybe a better idea would be to allow edits that are within code tags to be less than 6 char.

Comment: My advice would be that you should add a comment which highlights your suggested edit for that post. If OP agrees then he/she will self-edit.

Comment: I actually agree with Jeff on this one. I am yet to find a post where you can't legitimately change 6 characters... no one has posted one on meta complaining about this limit where I haven't been able to find 6 characters that need improvement... there are just so many little things you can improve that you should also do that. Unless, of course, the post is _just_ code in which case it's not that great a post.

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in the red message prompt.

Edits must be substantial.

[image]

You can always find formatting, spelling and grammar mistakes.

Comment: Changing code that does not compile to code that does compile... I call that substantial.